# Injectivity of a module over tensor product of group algebras

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $G$ be a finite group that is the direct product $G=H_1*H_2$ of two subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ with $H_1$ Abelian. Let $R[G]$ be the group ring and $M$ be a left $RG$-module (In this case, I know that $R[G]\simeq R[H_1]\otimes_R R[H_2]$).  Consider the $R[G]\otimes_R R[H_1]$-module $X=Hom_{R[H_2]}(R[G], M)$ (This makes sense because the elements of $G$ and $H_1$ commute in this case and this structure is defined as in Chapter IX of Cartan-Eilenberg's Homological Algebra on page 163). Suppose I know that  $X$ is injective over $R[G]$ (via the natural map $R[G]\rightarrow R[G]\otimes_R R[H_1]$), thus also injective over $R[H_1]$ since $R[G]$ is $R[H_1]$-free. I want to know if $X$ is injective over $R[G]\otimes_R R[H_1]$.

I Have tried to apply some isomorphisms given in Chapter IX of the aforementioned book; but I'm a bit confused with them. Also I guess this may follow from a general result concerning injective modules over tensor product of algebras, to which I'm not familiar. Comments are appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why $X$ is injective over $R[G]$. Consider the case $R=\mathbb{F}_p$, $H_1=H_2=C_p$ (cyclic of order $p$), and $M=R$.

Comment: This is part of my hypothesis. Maybe I should rewrite this sentence.